# what is the meaning of allow anonymous in wandb

Tags: machine-learning, wandb

i am trying to use wandb for visualization but I am confused about this line

andb_init_kwargs=dict(anonymous="allow") it means anyone can see visualization with having link ?

WandbCallback(
wandb_init_kwargs=dict(anonymous="allow"), # for Anonymous everyone can visualize progress
log_freq="batch",
)

Comment: please see https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/app/features/anon

Comment: I saw it means if I am using existing code from the internet to apply on my data .. the owner of the code can see my results too ??

Answer (score 0):

By using Anonymous mode, you can let others see your Wandb dashboard, run your code and even visualize results. To do so, they do not need to create a Weights & Biases account first. However, as per the [documentation](https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/app/features/anon), keep in mind that Anonymous-run links are sensitive since these links allow anyone to view and claim the results of an experiment for 7 days, so make sure to only share links with people you trust.